# how to use barcolor() to recolor 2 or 3 bars at the one time? pine script

Tags: pine-script

in pine script, I want to use barcolor() to recolor several bars at the one time, but only the first line is valid,I use two lines to reset the color like this:

```
barcolor(close < open ? color.black : color.white, offset=0)
barcolor(close < open ? color.black : color.white, offset=-1)
barcolor(close < open ? color.black : color.white, offset=-2)
```

I want to use barcolor() to recolor several bars at the one time

Comment: Can you give us example ? If the last bar are red-red-red-green-red, what result are you waiting for ?

Comment: for example, if high - low > atr, i want to color bar[0] to black,  and color bar[1] to black

Comment: my question is I can only color one bar ,  can not color 2 or 3 bars at one time, can you tell me how to Implement this effect? thanks

Comment: sorry, I find the reason!

Comment: Can you explain us ?

Comment: The conditions I set coincide, so the result is not what I expected